# Python - Setting a limit on a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I've just started to learn python, can anyone help me.
For example if I had a variable called 'speed' and I only wanted it to go to 100 and not above, and not to go below 0. But I also want the code to still run so I could set it lower or higher, my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
speed = 80
def onKeyPress(event, value):
    global speed 
    text.delete("%s-1c" % 'insert', 'insert')
    text.insert('end', 'Current Speed: %s\n\n' % (speed, ))
    speed += value 
    print(speed)
    if speed >= 100:
        text.insert('end', 'You have reached the speed limit')


speed = 80

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
text = tk.Text(root, background='black', foreground='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', 12))
text.pack()

# Individual key bindings
root.bind('<KeyPress-w>', lambda e: onKeyPress(e, 1)) 
root.bind('<KeyPress-s>', lambda e: onKeyPress(e, -1)) #

root.mainloop()
```

How would I get the 'speed' variable to stop at 100 without stopping the whole of the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of immediately changing `speed` with `speed += value`, do the following:

```
speed = min(max(speed+value, 0), 100)
```

This first produces the higher value between `speed+value` and `0`, so if it's negative, it will stay at 0. It then sends that to `min()` to find the lower value between it and `100`, so if it's higher than 100, it will stay at 100.

You can then change the check to `if speed == 100:`, since it won't go any higher.

Answer (score 4):

```
if speed >= 100:
    speed=100
    text.insert('end', 'You have reached the speed limit')
```